# Path в Raphael

Tags: raphael, javascript

Как нарисовать [такую вещь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDR3f.gif) с Raphael. Ещё, чтобы рисовалась только красная часть (остальное прозрачное) и чтобы красную часть можно было увеличить/уменьшить и анимировать изменение? + возможность залить это не только красным цветом, но и градиентом (линейным градиентом).

Вроде что-то писал, используя path, но не получается, что хочу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример номер [раз](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html)

Второй [пример](http://jsbin.com/usotu5/edit#preview)

Если что-то непонятно, могу дать подробный комментарий.

Вот [нарисовал](http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/GU5ZP/), специально для Вас.

Comment: А как заполнить это градиетом?

Comment: Ну, залить можно только внутреннюю часть

Comment: Значит плохо.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то это не под силу и в SVG сделать http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands

Правда у меня есть вариант сейчас постараюсь нарисовать, как это можно обойти.

Comment: Спасибо за полезный ответ.
<br />
Но я всё же сделал по-своему. <br />
Я нарисовал то же самое, только с помощью path (получилась замкнутая область), свойство stroke и stroke width я не использовал. Зато так, как я нарисовал, я могу заполнить область чем угодно + анимировать.
<br />
В чём я убедился, так это в том, что утром гораздо лучше программируется, чем ночью. Мне хватило всего 10 минут :)

Comment: Ну вот такие костыли получились: http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/kNM4c/

Тоже хотел предложить Вам через path :), поделитесь кодом для будущих поколений если не сложно. Ну и вопрос закрывайте ;)

А еще мы делали так, сначала мой дизайнер рисовал в чем-то типа Adobe Fireworks из чего можно выгрузить в SVG, а потом я конвертил это в объект Raphael.